Using SWIG to wrap a class member function that returns std::tuple
I'm attempting to wrap a class using swig. The class has a member function called readKeyword that returns a std::tuple< std::uint32_t,std::int32_t,std::uint64_t,std::int64_t,double,std::string >.
There seems to be a type-mismatch between what readkeyword is returning and the SwigValueWrapper instance that the return is being stored into.
Here's some info about the class I'm trying to wrap.
//CArcFitsFile.h

...

#include <string>
 
#ifdef __cpp_lib_variant
    #include <variant>
#else
    #include <tuple>
#endif

...

namespace arc
{
    namespace gen3
    {
 
        namespace fits
        {
 
            using BPP_16 = std::uint16_t;
 
            using BPP_32 = std::uint32_t;
 
 
            #ifdef __cpp_lib_variant
                using keywordValue_t = std::variant<std::uint32_t, std::int32_t, std::uint64_t, std::int64_t, double, std::string>;
            #else
                using keywordValue_t = std::tuple<std::uint32_t, std::int32_t, std::uint64_t, std::int64_t, double, std::string>;
            #endif

...

        template <typename T = arc::gen3::fits::BPP_16>
        class GEN3_CARCFITSFILE_API CArcFitsFile : public arc::gen3::CArcBase
        {
            public:
 
                CArcFitsFile( void );
 
                virtual ~CArcFitsFile( void );
...
                arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t readKeyword( const std::string& sKey, arc::gen3::fits::e_Type eType );
...

Here's my interface file
//ArcFits.i

%define ModuleDocStr
"Python interface to CArcDeinterlace C++ code."
%enddef

%feature("autodoc", "1");
%module(package="ArcLib", docstring=ModuleDocStr) ArcFitsFile

%{
#include <filesystem>
#include <version>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <tuple>

#include <CArcFitsFileDllMain.h>
#include <CArcStringList.h>
#include <CArcBase.h>
#include <fitsio.h>
#include <CArcFitsFile.h>
%}

%init %{
%}

#define __attribute__(x)
#define GEN3_CARCFITSFILE_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))

// Specifies the default C++ to python exception handling interface
%exception {
    try {
        $action
    } catch (std::domain_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::invalid_argument & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::length_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::out_of_range & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::logic_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::range_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::underflow_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::overflow_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::runtime_error & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (std::exception & e) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_Exception, e.what());
        SWIG_fail;
    } catch (...) {
        SWIG_fail;
    }
}
%include "std_unique_ptr.i"
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "std_string.i"
%include "CArcFitsFile.h"

//%template(arcDeinterlaceUint8) arc::gen3::CArcDeinterlace<uint8_t>;
%template(arcFitsFileUint16) arc::gen3::CArcFitsFile<arc::gen3::fits::BPP_16>;
%template(arcFitsFileUint32) arc::gen3::CArcFitsFile<arc::gen3::fits::BPP_32>;

When the compiler compiles the generated wrapper code, I get a compiler error in both the arcFitsFileUint16 and arcFitsFileUint32 templates for the readKeyword member function:
running build_ext
building '_ArcFitsFile' extension
swigging ArcLib/ArcFitsFile.i to ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp
swig -python -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcDeinterlace/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcImage/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcAPIClient/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcDisplay/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcBase/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcDevice/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/cfitsio-3450/include -Iinclude -Iinclude -c++ -Wall -o ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp ArcLib/ArcFitsFile.i
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:206: Warning 345: Unable to deduce auto return type for 'MAKE_POINT(std::uint32_t,std::uint32_t)' (ignored).
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:522: Warning 317: Specialization of non-template 'default_delete'.
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:269: Warning 321: 'open' conflicts with a built-in name in python
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:269: Warning 321: 'open' conflicts with a built-in name in python
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:269: Warning 321: 'open' conflicts with a built-in name in python
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:269: Warning 321: 'open' conflicts with a built-in name in python
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:216: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'arc::gen3::CArcBase'. Ignored.
src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:216: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'arc::gen3::CArcBase'. Ignored.
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcDeinterlace/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcImage/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcAPIClient/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcDisplay/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcBase/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcDevice/inc -Isrc/ARC_API/3.6.2/cfitsio-3450/include -Iinclude -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.o -std=c++20
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:5306:67: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ and ‘arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t’ {aka ‘std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’})
 5306 |       result = (arg1)->readKeyword((std::string const &)*arg2,arg3);
      |                                                                   ^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3209:21: note: candidate: ‘SwigValueWrapper<T>& SwigValueWrapper<T>::operator=(const SwigValueWrapper<T>&) [with T = std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
 3209 |   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const SwigValueWrapper<T>& rhs);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3209:58: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t’ {aka ‘std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’} to ‘const SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&’
 3209 |   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const SwigValueWrapper<T>& rhs);
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3213:21: note: candidate: ‘SwigValueWrapper<T>& SwigValueWrapper<T>::operator=(const T&) [with T = std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
 3213 |   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const T& t) { SwigSmartPointer tmp(new T(t)); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3213:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t’ {aka ‘std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’} to ‘const std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&’
 3213 |   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const T& t) { SwigSmartPointer tmp(new T(t)); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3215:21: note: candidate: ‘SwigValueWrapper<T>& SwigValueWrapper<T>::operator=(T&&) [with T = std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]’
 3215 |   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(T&& t) { SwigSmartPointer tmp(new T(std::move(t))); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
      |                     ^~~~~~~~
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3215:35: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t’ {aka ‘std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >’} to ‘std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&&’
 3215 |   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(T&& t) { SwigSmartPointer tmp(new T(std::move(t))); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
      |                               ~~~~^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:5341:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::variant(SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)’
 5341 |   resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t(result)), SWIGTYPE_p_std__tupleT_std__uint32_t_std__int32_t_std__uint64_t_std__int64_t_double_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
      |                                                                             ^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:1140:89: note: in definition of macro ‘SWIG_NewPointerObj’
 1140 | #define SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr, type, flags)            SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(NULL, ptr, type, flags)
      |                                                                                         ^~~
In file included from src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:27,
                 from ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3337:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1450:9: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int _Np, class _Up, class ... _Args, class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, std::initializer_list<_Up>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = _Np; _Up = _Up; _Args = {_Args ...}; _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-5> = <template-parameter-1-5>; _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1450 |         variant(in_place_index_t<_Np>, initializer_list<_Up> __il,
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1450:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:5341:77: note:   ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ is not derived from ‘std::in_place_index_t<_Idx>’
 5341 |   resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t(result)), SWIGTYPE_p_std__tupleT_std__uint32_t_std__int32_t_std__uint64_t_std__int64_t_double_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
      |                                                                             ^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:1140:89: note: in definition of macro ‘SWIG_NewPointerObj’
 1140 | #define SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr, type, flags)            SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(NULL, ptr, type, flags)
      |                                                                                         ^~~
In file included from src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:27,
                 from ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3337:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1439:9: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int _Np, class ... _Args, class _Tp, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&& ...) [with long unsigned int _Np = _Np; _Args = {_Args ...}; _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-4> = <template-parameter-1-4>; _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1439 |         variant(in_place_index_t<_Np>, _Args&&... __args)
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1439:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:5341:77: note:   ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ is not derived from ‘std::in_place_index_t<_Idx>’
 5341 |   resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t(result)), SWIGTYPE_p_std__tupleT_std__uint32_t_std__int32_t_std__uint64_t_std__int64_t_double_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
      |                                                                             ^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:1140:89: note: in definition of macro ‘SWIG_NewPointerObj’
 1140 | #define SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr, type, flags)            SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(NULL, ptr, type, flags)
      |                                                                                         ^~~
In file included from src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:27,
                 from ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3337:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1429:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Up, class ... _Args, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>, std::initializer_list<_Up>, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = _Tp; _Up = _Up; _Args = {_Args ...}; <template-parameter-2-4> = <template-parameter-1-4>; _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1429 |         variant(in_place_type_t<_Tp>, initializer_list<_Up> __il,
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1429:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:5341:77: note:   ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ is not derived from ‘std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>’
 5341 |   resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t(result)), SWIGTYPE_p_std__tupleT_std__uint32_t_std__int32_t_std__uint64_t_std__int64_t_double_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
      |                                                                             ^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:1140:89: note: in definition of macro ‘SWIG_NewPointerObj’
 1140 | #define SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr, type, flags)            SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(NULL, ptr, type, flags)
      |                                                                                         ^~~
In file included from src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:27,
                 from ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3337:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1419:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class ... _Args, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>, _Args&& ...) [with _Tp = _Tp; _Args = {_Args ...}; <template-parameter-2-3> = <template-parameter-1-3>; _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1419 |         variant(in_place_type_t<_Tp>, _Args&&... __args)
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1419:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:5341:77: note:   ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ is not derived from ‘std::in_place_type_t<_Tp>’
 5341 |   resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t(result)), SWIGTYPE_p_std__tupleT_std__uint32_t_std__int32_t_std__uint64_t_std__int64_t_double_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
      |                                                                             ^
ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:1140:89: note: in definition of macro ‘SWIG_NewPointerObj’
 1140 | #define SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr, type, flags)            SWIG_Python_NewPointerObj(NULL, ptr, type, flags)
      |                                                                                         ^~~
In file included from src/ARC_API/3.6.2/CArcFitsFile/inc/CArcFitsFile.h:27,
                 from ArcLib/ArcFitsFile_wrap.cpp:3337:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1409:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class, class, class _Tj, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(_Tp&&) [with _Tp = _Tp; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; <template-parameter-2-3> = <template-parameter-1-3>; _Tj = _Tj; <template-parameter-2-5> = <template-parameter-1-5>; _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1409 |         variant(_Tp&& __t)
      |         ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1409:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant: In substitution of ‘template<class ... _Types> template<class _Tp, class> using __accepted_type = std::variant<_Types>::__to_type<__accepted_index<_Tp> > [with _Tp = SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’:
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1405:9:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1375:15: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
 1375 |         using __accepted_type = __to_type<__accepted_index<_Tp>>;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1397:7: note: candidate: ‘std::variant<_Types>::variant(std::variant<_Types>&&) [with _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1397 |       variant(variant&&) = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1397:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ to ‘std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&&’
 1397 |       variant(variant&&) = default;
      |               ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1396:7: note: candidate: ‘std::variant<_Types>::variant(const std::variant<_Types>&) [with _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1396 |       variant(const variant& __rhs) = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1396:30: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SwigValueWrapper<std::tuple<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >’ to ‘const std::variant<unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&’
 1396 |       variant(const variant& __rhs) = default;
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/variant:1395:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant() [with _Types = {unsigned int, int, long unsigned int, long int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}]’
 1395 |       variant() = default;
      |       ^~~~~~~

.... and similar for ‘PyObject* _wrap_arcFitsFileUint32_readKeyword.
And here's the generated wrapper code (included line numbers just for the heck of it):
 5268 SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
 5269   PyObject *resultobj = 0;
 5270   arc::gen3::CArcFitsFile< arc::gen3::fits::BPP_16 > *arg1 = (arc::gen3::CArcFitsFile< arc::gen3::fits::BPP_16 > *) 0 ;
 5271   std::string *arg2 = 0 ;
 5272   arc::gen3::fits::e_Type arg3 ;
 5273   void *argp1 = 0 ;
 5274   int res1 = 0 ;
 5275   int res2 = SWIG_OLDOBJ ;
 5276   int val3 ;
 5277   int ecode3 = 0 ;
 5278   PyObject *swig_obj[3] ;
 5279   SwigValueWrapper< std::tuple< std::uint32_t,std::int32_t,std::uint64_t,std::int64_t,double,std::string > > result;
 5280 
 5281   (void)self;
 5282   if (!SWIG_Python_UnpackTuple(args, "arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword", 3, 3, swig_obj)) SWIG_fail;
 5283   res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(swig_obj[0], &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_arc__gen3__CArcFitsFileT_arc__gen3__fits__BPP_16_t, 0 |  0 );
 5284   if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
 5285     SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "a      rc::gen3::CArcFitsFile< arc::gen3::fits::BPP_16 > *""'");
 5286   }
 5287   arg1 = reinterpret_cast< arc::gen3::CArcFitsFile< arc::gen3::fits::BPP_16 > * >(argp1);
 5288   {
 5289     std::string *ptr = (std::string *)0;
 5290     res2 = SWIG_AsPtr_std_string(swig_obj[1], &ptr);
 5291     if (!SWIG_IsOK(res2)) {
 5292       SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res2), "in method '" "arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword" "', argument " "2"" of type '"       "std::string const &""'");
 5293     }
 5294     if (!ptr) {
 5295       SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ValueError, "invalid null reference " "in method '" "arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword" "', argum      ent " "2"" of type '" "std::string const &""'");
 5296     }
 5297     arg2 = ptr;
 5298   }
 5299   ecode3 = SWIG_AsVal_int(swig_obj[2], &val3);
 5300   if (!SWIG_IsOK(ecode3)) {
 5301     SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(ecode3), "in method '" "arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword" "', argument " "3"" of type '"       "arc::gen3::fits::e_Type""'");
 5302   }
 5303   arg3 = static_cast< arc::gen3::fits::e_Type >(val3);
 5304   {
 5305     try {
 5306       result = (arg1)->readKeyword((std::string const &)*arg2,arg3);
 5307     } catch (std::domain_error & e) {
 5308       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, e.what());
 5309       SWIG_fail;
 5310     } catch (std::invalid_argument & e) {
 5311       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, e.what());
 5312       SWIG_fail;
 5313     } catch (std::length_error & e) {
 5314       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, e.what());
 5315       SWIG_fail;
 5316     } catch (std::out_of_range & e) {
 5317       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, e.what());
 5318       SWIG_fail;
 5319     } catch (std::logic_error & e) {
 5320       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what());
 5321       SWIG_fail;
 5322     } catch (std::range_error & e) {
 5323       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, e.what());
 5324       SWIG_fail;
 5325     } catch (std::underflow_error & e) {
 5326       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ArithmeticError, e.what());
 5327       SWIG_fail;
 5328     } catch (std::overflow_error & e) {
 5329       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_OverflowError, e.what());
 5330       SWIG_fail;
 5331     } catch (std::runtime_error & e) {
 5332       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, e.what());
 5333       SWIG_fail;
 5334     } catch (std::exception & e) {
 5335       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_Exception, e.what());
 5336       SWIG_fail;
 5337     } catch (...) {
 5338       SWIG_fail;
 5339     }
 5340   }
 5341   resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj((new arc::gen3::fits::keywordValue_t(result)), SWIGTYPE_p_std__tupleT_std__uint32_t_std__in      t32_t_std__uint64_t_std__int64_t_double_std__string_t, SWIG_POINTER_OWN |  0 );
 5342   if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res2)) delete arg2;
 5343   return resultobj;
 5344 fail:
 5345   if (SWIG_IsNewObj(res2)) delete arg2;
 5346   return NULL;
 5347 }

These are the allowed operators for SwigValueWrapper (also from the generated wrapper code):
 3201 template<typename T> class SwigValueWrapper {
 3202   struct SwigSmartPointer {
 3203     T *ptr;
 3204     SwigSmartPointer(T *p) : ptr(p) { }
 3205     ~SwigSmartPointer() { delete ptr; }
 3206     SwigSmartPointer& operator=(SwigSmartPointer& rhs) { T* oldptr = ptr; ptr = 0; delete oldptr; ptr = rhs.ptr; rhs.ptr = 0; r      eturn *this; }
 3207     void reset(T *p) { T* oldptr = ptr; ptr = 0; delete oldptr; ptr = p; }
 3208   } pointer;
 3209   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const SwigValueWrapper<T>& rhs);
 3210   SwigValueWrapper(const SwigValueWrapper<T>& rhs);
 3211 public:
 3212   SwigValueWrapper() : pointer(0) { }
 3213   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const T& t) { SwigSmartPointer tmp(new T(t)); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
 3214 #if __cplusplus >=201103L
 3215   SwigValueWrapper& operator=(T&& t) { SwigSmartPointer tmp(new T(std::move(t))); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
 3216   operator T&&() const { return std::move(*pointer.ptr); }
 3217 #else
 3218   operator T&() const { return *pointer.ptr; }
 3219 #endif
 3220   T *operator&() const { return pointer.ptr; }
 3221   static void reset(SwigValueWrapper& t, T *p) { t.pointer.reset(p); }
 3222 };

It seems to me the issue here is that result and the return value for readKeyword are type-mismatched, but why? And how might I go about getting them matched?
Maybe SWIG doesn't play nicely with tuples? I've looked and there doesn't seem to be an interface for std::tuple. But I would expect for _wrap_arcFitsFileUint16_readKeyword to return a std::tuple * at the very least.
I'm somewhat new to SWIG and am learning, but I don't yet know all the ins and outs. Thanks.
UPDATE
This wasn't a tuple issue at all. See my solution below.

I solved it. Somewhere during compilation the preprocessor was including <variant>.
I was using #include <tuple> in my interface file, so I had assumed __cpp_lib_variant would remain undefined while I was compiling the wrapper code.
Adding the following preprocessor directives to my interface file allowed my code to compile.
#ifdef __cpp_lib_variant
        #undef __cpp_lib_variant
#endif
#include <tuple>

